# Why am I getting 'str' object has no attribute 'get' on form_valid?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have looked at other questions regarding this error but can't seem to pinpoint the issue on mine.  I know there are better ways to do some of the things I am trying to do in the following code, but right now I'm just trying to pinpoint the culprit causing the following error.

```
Internal Server Error: /users/create/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/venv_mymanagedservices/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/venv_mymanagedservices/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 138, in __call__
response = self.process_response(request, response)
File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/venv_mymanagedservices/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py", line 32, in process_response
if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
[26/Mar/2017 23:02:14] "POST /users/create/ HTTP/1.1" 500 72448
```

Here's the view where I am trying to create a new user:

```
class CustomerUserCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
model = User
template_name = 'users/user_create.html'
fields = ['username', 'name', 'email', 'password']

# Search for which customer the user is assigned to and deny access if not a customer user or superuser
def render_to_response(self, context):
    customer_admins = Customer.objects.filter(users=self.request.user)
    if not (customer_admins or self.request.user.is_superuser):
        return redirect('/403')
    else:
        return super(CustomerUserCreate, self).render_to_response(context)

def get_form(self, form_class=None):
    form = super(CustomerUserCreate,self).get_form(form_class) #instantiate using parent
    customer_admins = Customer.objects.get(users=self.request.user)
    # Add a field that allows user to select which companies should be added to the Company models' users field.
    form.fields['companies'] = forms.models.ModelMultipleChoiceField(Company.objects.filter(customer=customer_admins))
    form.fields['companies'].widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
    return form

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('users:list')

def form_valid(self, form):
    customer_admins = Customer.objects.filter(users=self.request.user)
    if not (customer_admins or self.request.user.is_superuser):
        return redirect('/403')

    companies_data = form.cleaned_data['companies']
    del form.cleaned_data['companies']
    # Record which customer account this user should be associated with
    form.instance.created_by_customer = Customer.objects.get(users=self.request.user)
    new_user = User.objects.create_user(username=form.cleaned_data['username'], email=form.cleaned_data['email'], name=form.cleaned_data['name'], password=form.cleaned_data['password'])
    if companies_data:
        for company in companies_data:
            company.users.add(new_user)
    else:
        messages.add_message(self.request, messages.WARNING, 'You must select at least 1 company for the new user.')
        return reverse('users:create')
    # Add a success message
    messages.add_message(self.request, messages.SUCCESS, 'User Created.')
    return reverse('users:list')
```

Does anyone have a clearer head than I do about this one?  I think I may just be confusing myself with all that I'm trying to do and completely missing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, as you may have noticed, I was saving the new user in form_valid because I needed to use the create_user function, but then I was returning the form that wasn't necessary anymore.  Instead of returning form, I return new_user and that seems to work.  Still not sure this is best way to go about letting clients create new users on the front end, but it seems to work.

```
return super(CustomerUserCreate, self).form_valid(new_user)
```